# Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Index (Error)

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, git-extensions

I have been using git extensions with Visual Studio 2013 for months.  Yesterday my Visual Studio froze.  I had to restart in order to shut it down. Now, I can get in and things appear to work, except git extensions.

I have this error message on the Git Settings tab:

`An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Index (Error).
Invalid data in index - incorrect header signature`

I have:

1. uninstalled and re-installed git
2. restarted my machine
3. spent hours searching online
4. tried re-cloning the repository

None of this has had any effect. I don't know what caused it and I don't know how to fix it.

Has anyone encountered this before?  How do I get it to work again?  I have changes that I need to commit.

Comment: It sounds like your index file is corrupt, which would not affect other repositories; you get the same error working with a different clone of this repo?

Comment: What does `git status` from the command line indicate?

Comment: I got the same result when I created a new clone.  `git status` says `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): git`

Comment: I just tried `git status` on the new clone and got this: `# On branch master nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Comment: GitExtensions not uses libgit2. Probably you have installed Visual Studio Tools for Git, it's different product

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2013, so Tools for Git is built-in.  I have GitExtensions installed (and typically use it for commits).  However, inside or out of VS, GitExtensions will not visibly do anything when I try to execute any of the commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are describing two issues.

First, your GitExtensions may be corrupted (delete the contents of /Users/{User}/AppData/Roaming/GitExtensions)

Second, VS may be connecting to a repository with issues.  If you clone a new repository and connect to it, do you still get that error?

Comment: You are correct on the libgit2 issue.  I will try the other to see if it fixes the GitExtensions issues.

Comment: I had a clean installation on a laptop and copied the contents of that folder into my broken desktop and all works now.  Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Check your .gitignore file

examples are here:
https://github.com/github/gitignore

Not every file need to be commited, because some of them are local for your compiler

Comment: This was the cause for me getting the error.  I excluded the gitignore file and the error went away.